# Ignore SMS if it contains a keyword

Tags: android, regex, filter, ignore-case

In my app I have to scan all the user sms and filter it based on some keywords.for that I can use `smsBody.contains(filterKey)` directly. but suppose the filter key is like ***you have earned<>+Rewards*** where <> should have some numbers. ie., ***you have earned 1000 Rewards***, if this string comes in the sms I have to reject that. I have added my code below

```
if (!shouldIgnore(smsBody)) {
  //further process
} else {
    LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "ignoring message : " + smsBody);
}



public boolean shouldIgnore(String body) {
    ListIterator<String> listIterator =mList.listIterator()

    while(listIterator.hasNext()){
      String key = listIterator.next();

      if(smsBody.contains(key)){
        return true;
    }
}
return false
}
```

String.contains() will return true only if the exact key comes, but in this case key may not be exact.
how do I modify this method ?

Comment: What do you mean by "reject" and "ignore"?

Comment: What is meaning of **if this string comes in the sms I have to reject that**?

Comment: I have to avoid that perticular sms, mean I dont want that sms. I have to find if the key is found in the sms body

Comment: you mean you wish to delete that sms from system?

Comment: @AnswerDroid no I don't want to delete, just ignore that sms,

Comment: In should ignore, what is the mList and smsBody?

Comment: Use a regex `you have earned \\d+ Rewards`. If a match is found, reject the sms. [`if ("you have earned 1000 Rewards".matches("you have earned \\d+ Rewards")) {System.out.println("REJECT IT!");}`](https://ideone.com/fchDhO).

Comment: can you explain this /

Comment: @VividVervet: Does it work for you? If yes, I will post with explanations.

Comment: Actually, taking into account *this case key may not be exact*, I think you'd  better use `if ("you have earned 1000 Rewards".matches("(?i).*\\byou have earned \\d+ Rewards\\b.*")`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to understand you very well, but let me know if I missed something. Regex will do the job:

```
public boolean shouldIgnore(String body) {
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("you have earned [0-9]+ Rewards");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(body);
   return m.find();
}
```

`[0-9]+` looks for any integer between `you have earned` and `Rewards`, and Matcher will return `true` if finds pattern in `body`, else, will return `false`.

In addition, you could use `String.matches` method as explained in comments.

Comment: Why don't you explain why what you post should work? *Try this*, *try that* - really, IMHO, is not the best answering style.

Comment: I did not say anything about deleting. If you want to get as many upvotes as possible, I'd add more explanations to the answer. It is an advice. Take it if you please. You do not have to. Code only answers are often flagged and later deleted.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for that.

Comment: Good. Now it looks better, but I'd avoid using "I am note sure" as it assumes the question is  unclear and should be closed rather than answered.